# unable to check for a pattern in a string

Tags: perl

All I want to check is that whether "free" occurs in word boundary or not and this is not working(prints nothing):

```
use strict;

my @words= ("free hotmail msn");

my $free = "free";

$free =~ s/.*/\b$&\b/;


if ( $words[0] =~ m/$free/)
{
    print "found\n";
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the substitution? Why don't you just say `if ($words[0] =~ m/\b$free\b/) { ... }`? You don't need all the other stuff, especially not the substitution.

Comment: @simbabque I want to wrap the pattern with \b. How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is write

```
my $free = 'free';

$free = qr/\b$free\b/;

print "found" if $words[0] =~ $free;
```

But if your `@words` array is supposed to contain a single word per element then you are more likely to want

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @words= qw( free hotmail msn );

my $free = "free";

print "found\n" if $words[0] eq $free;
```

Comment: you've misunderstood my question. Looks like I need to write $free =~ s/.*/\\b$&\\b/;  instead of $free =~ s/.*/\b$&\b/;

Comment: @AgA: you said you wanted to *check ... whether "free" occurs in word boundary*. There is no need to add `\b` to the ends of `$free` itself when what you want is a regex, but if you insist on doing that you are best off writing `$free = "\\b$free\\b"` or `$free = '\b'.$free.'\b';

Answer (score 1):

In a pattern replacement, as in a double quoted string, `\b` is interpreted as the backspace character (`chr(8)` on most systems).

```
$free =~ s/.*/\\b$&\\b/;
```

is an awkward way of writing one of

```
$free = '\b' . $free . '\b';
$free = "\\b$free\\b";
```

but it will do the job.